# Design 3-digit solution without using any arithmetic. (Hint: use scanf.)

Tags: c

I am currently learning C as part of a course and I have a task to reverse the order of a number without using any arithmetic [Design 3-digit solution without using any arithmetic (Hint: use scanf)]. I currently have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int n;
    printf("Enter a two-digit number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("The reversal is: %d%d\n", n % 10, n / 10);

    return 0;
}
```

I EXPECT THE OUTPUT OF 123 TO BE 321 BUT THE ACTUAL OUTPUT IS 312

Comment: 123 isn't a 2 digit number though. It looks like your code is hard-coded to only work with 2 digit numbers.

Comment: I think what your homework assignment is getting at, is that instead of reading in a number as an integer (`%d`) and then doing arithmetic (like you are currently doing), read in the number as 3 characters (`%c%c%c`) and then just display the characters in reverse order.

Comment: Or read into a large buffer using %s and print each character from last to first. That has the advantage of working for any number of digits up to the length of the provided buffer, even if the number is too large to fit in an int or long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code utilizes the right method to achieve the task at hand. However, it's hard coded to work with only 2 digit numbers.

To print the unit digit, you print num%10.

To print the tens digit, you print (num/10)%10.

To print the hundreds digit, you print (num/100)%10.

The pattern here is:

```
1                   10                   100                  ...      1n
(num/(10^0))%10     (num/(10^1))%10      (num/(10^2))%10               (num/(10^(n)))%10
```

Using this logic, you can modify your code to work with 3 digit numbers like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int n;
    printf("Enter a two-digit number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("The reversal is: %d%d%d\n", n % 10, n / 10 % 10,n / 10 / 10);
    //printf("The reversal is: %d%d%d\n", n % 10, n / 10 % 10, n / 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Happy coding and welcome to Stack Overflow!